# How to select a document if a field contains a substring

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-mango

I've a movielens database and, for example, to search all the documents who have "Titanic" in the title i run this Mango query:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "$or": [
         {
            "Title": {
               "$regex": "titanic"
            }
         },
         {
            "Title": {
               "$regex": "Titanic"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And I have what I want. So my question now is: is possible to select a document only if I remember a substring?

For example, for the title "Tomb raider", I remember that contains  "raider". I've tried with regex but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `(?i)` to make the `regex` case insensitive.

Place `.*` in front and at the end of the search term "titanic" for matching any character zero or more times.

```
{
  "selector": {
    "Title": {
      "$regex": "(?i).*titanic.*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank toy. Another question if you can: Do you know if it is possible to search on the basis of a substring? for example: title is "The Lion King" and i would search only "king"

Comment: @Malotino: That's what the selector in my answer does, searching by a substring. Simply use `"$regex": "(?i).*king.*"`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got confused. I realized it only made CouchDB case insensitive. Thanks so much